# Task is not re-triggered even if variables in vardeps change

Tags: yocto, bitbake

I have an issue related to vardeps where I am making a task dependent on some variables.

I have created some new variables e.g., `NEW_VARIABLE`, added them to `BB_ENV_EXTRAWHITE`. In some recipes, I wrote my own implementation of some tasks that are dependent on these new variables, and for this dependency to work I added  e.g., `do_install[vardeps] = "NEW_VARIABLE"`, so I am now expecting that every time I change this `NEW_VARIABLE` and perform e.g., `bitbake recipename`, the `do_install` task should run. I checked the task signature and I see the `NEW_VARIABLE` there.

Let's assum I have two possible values for this variable. When I set the variable for the first time "value1", i.e., the first build, everything works and there is no problem. When I change its value to the other value "value2" not used before and build the recipe again, the `do_install` will also run and no problem occurs. The problem is however, if I set the variable again to the old value "value1", and I execite `bitbake recipename` again. The `do_install` will not be re-triggered, and this leads to some wrong/old data located in `work` directory, and also produced in the image.

I tried setting `BB_DONT_CACHE`, as I understood in an old question that the problem might be that the recipe needs to be parsed again, however this did not work at all.

I do not want to always run the tasks when I perform a new build, i.e., `do_install[[nostamp] = "1"` so this solution can not be regarded. I just want it to run again every time I change this `NEW_VARIABLE`.

Is what I am expecting a normal behavior? Or Yocto does not work this way?

Answer (score 0):

I faced same issue all day, also tried vardeps BB_DONT_CACHE etc but then I changed into  using SRC_URI but still got same behavior. Like you I build a separate recipe "bitbake name" and look in the work image/ for the recipe output. For me it turns out that I just think that this will be updated just as if I make other new changes. But once I change input to something old the state cache kicks in and the work dir is left alone - fooling me to think it does not work properly. But when I build the final image-base it is properly populated. I guess one need to force build or disregard compiler cache to get the output this way.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. You are right that in the final image you would find everything populated. The thing is, they are not "new"; Yocto just gets these files from some cache, even if they are not in the work directory, and put them in the image, so you would find that these files, populated in the final image, have an older date than your build, which I do not want, I want the task to run because I made changes and see new output in the image.  

I tried  `bitbake -c clean recipename` then `bitbake recipename` but it is not working, no new files in work dir and hence no new files in image.